# WebDriverError: File not found

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am getting this Selenium WebDriver error:

```
WebDriverError: File not found: /Users/foo/bar/nabisco/cdt-now/csv-data/IT-DE-Yasper.csv
```

the thing is, this file totally exists on the filesystem. The selenium server is running locally. So I am not sure why it cannot find the file. Anybody know?

Comment: can u paste your code snippet

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox 55, a recent bug causes this exception to occur even if the file is present.
See https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/858.

Until the bug is fixed, there is a workaround: setting the Firefox preference "dom.file.createInChild" to "true".

For instance:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("dom.file.createInChild", true);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```